# Source page to Live Copy page changes are not reflecting in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, aem-6

First I tried to a Launch Page, a launch page is a Live Copy of the Source page with rolloutconfig being pushonmodify.

But no matter what I do, any changes that I make on the source page they do not reflect on the Launch Page.

I also tried creating an actual Live Copy using siteadmin but even the same problem appears for manually created LiveCopies.

I have checked the logs and there is nothing present in it.

Why is this happening?

Is there any configuration that I have missed and that is why this is happening?

Comment: Does the Live copies work using standard rollout config or another configuration besides Push On Modify?

Comment: @ronnyfm
Push on Modify. I've seen it in the node properties. Worst thing is that nothing shows up in the error logs.